# Sums of specifics values in a (grouped ?) list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list that looks like this

```
Name | Code | //More_Columns
Bob    0000   ...
David  6001   ...
David  6000   ...
Jack   0      ...
Jack   1234   ...
Bob    7777   ...
```

I managed to retrieve the number of unique Names by using `List.GroupBy(O => O.Name).Count();` that shall give me 3 here

Now i need to Count the number of some values by their Code like this :

- **OkCodes** will be 0 or 0000 codes
- **ErrorCodes** will be 6000 or 6001 codes
- **UnknowCodes** will be all others ones

So here each var will be at 2

I tried so far to `group by` lists by their code into sublists, but i can't, or don't know how, Sum all keys of each group

```
var GroupedList = List.GroupBy(O => O.Code);
var OkList = GroupedList.Where(O => O.Key == "0" || O.Key == "0000");
var ErrorList = GroupedList.Where(O => O.Key == "6001" || O.Key == "6000");
var UnknowList = GroupedList.Where(O => O.Key != "0" && O.Key != "0000" && O.Key != "6001" && O.Key != "6000");
```

Plus it looks like a very heavy method when i bet there something better to do, with linq or something but i can't do something fitting. Any advice will be appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Conditional Groupby in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23894174/conditional-groupby-in-linq)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that by one LINQ query. This technique also works with LINQ to Entities:

```cs
var query =
    from o in List
    group o by 1 into g
    select new 
    {
        OkCodes = g.Count(x => x.Code == "0" || x.Code == "0000"),
        ErrorCodes = g.Count(x => x.Code == "6001" || x.Code == "6000");
        UnknowCodes = g.Count(x => x.Code != "0" && x.Code != "0000" && x.Code != "6001" && x.Code != "6000");
    }

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 1):

You might create your own code class:

```
public class Code
{
   public string Value { get; }

   public Code(string value)
   {
      this.Value = value;
   }

   public override bool Equals(object other)
   {
      return other is Code code && this.Value == code.Value;
   }

   public override int GetHashCode()
   {
      return this.Value.GetHashCode();
   }

   public bool IsOkCode => Value == "0" || Value == "0000";

   public bool IsErrorCode => Value == "6000" || Value == "6001";

   public bool IsUnknownCode => !IsOkCode && !IsErrorCode;
}
```

With this class, counting will be very easy (you don't need `GroupBy`):

```
int amountOkCodes = List.Count(x => x.Code.IsOkCode);
int amountErrorCodes = List.Count(x => x.Code.IsErrorCode);
int amountUnknownCodes = List.Count(x => x.Code.IsUnknownCode);
```

Online demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/g0GHZe